# ipywidgets is not supporting in python terminal

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am trying to run below code using python terminal, it works completely fine when i run in jupyter notebook, but in ubuntu terminal it throws error. even tried running

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
```

on the terminal still I receive same error

```
import matplotlib as mp
from pylab import *
from sklearn import datasets
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

faces = datasets.fetch_olivetti_faces()

class Trainer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.results = {}
        self.imgs = faces.images
        self.index = 0

    def increment_face(self):
        if self.index + 1 >= len(self.imgs):
            return self.index
        else:
            while str(self.index) in self.results:
                print(self.index)
                self.index += 1
            return self.index

    def record_result(self, smile=True):
        self.results[str(self.index)] = smile

trainer = Trainer()

button_smile = widgets.Button(description='smile')
button_no_smile = widgets.Button(description='sad face')

def display_face(face):
    clear_output()
    imshow(face, cmap='gray')
    axis('off')
    show()

def update_smile(b):
    trainer.record_result(smile=True)
    trainer.increment_face()
    display_face(trainer.imgs[trainer.index])

def update_no_smile(b):
    trainer.record_result(smile=False)
    trainer.increment_face()
    display_face(trainer.imgs[trainer.index])

button_no_smile.on_click(update_no_smile)
button_smile.on_click(update_smile)

display(button_smile)
display(button_no_smile)
display_face(trainer.imgs[trainer.index])
```

Traceback error when I was running from python terminal

```
Widget Javascript not detected.  It may not be installed properly. Did you enable the widgetsnbextension? If not, then run "jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/harish/anaconda3/envs/facial_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    880             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    881             if method is not None:
--> 882                 method()
    883                 return True
    884 

/home/harish/anaconda3/envs/facial_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/widget.py in _ipython_display_(self, **kwargs)
    480                 loud_error('The installed widget Javascript is the wrong version.')
    481 
--> 482             self._send({"method": "display"})
    483             self._handle_displayed(**kwargs)
    484 

/home/harish/anaconda3/envs/facial_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/widget.py in _send(self, msg, buffers)
    485     def _send(self, msg, buffers=None):
    486         """Sends a message to the model in the front-end."""
--> 487         self.comm.send(data=msg, buffers=buffers)
    488 
    489 

/home/harish/anaconda3/envs/facial_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/comm.py in send(self, data, metadata, buffers)
    119         """Send a message to the frontend-side version of this comm"""
    120         self._publish_msg('comm_msg',
--> 121             data=data, metadata=metadata, buffers=buffers,
    122         )
    123 

/home/harish/anaconda3/envs/facial_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/comm.py in _publish_msg(self, msg_type, data, metadata, buffers, **keys)
     64         metadata = {} if metadata is None else metadata
     65         content = json_clean(dict(data=data, comm_id=self.comm_id, **keys))
---> 66         self.kernel.session.send(self.kernel.iopub_socket, msg_type,
     67             content,
     68             metadata=json_clean(metadata),

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'session'
<ipywidgets.widgets.widget_button.Button at 0x7f0de5ebfb38>
Widget Javascript not detected.  It may not be installed properly. Did you enable the widgetsnbextension? If not, then run "jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/harish/anaconda3/envs/facial_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    880             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    881             if method is not None:
--> 882                 method()
    883                 return True
    884 

/home/harish/anaconda3/envs/facial_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/widget.py in _ipython_display_(self, **kwargs)
    480                 loud_error('The installed widget Javascript is the wrong version.')
    481 
--> 482             self._send({"method": "display"})
    483             self._handle_displayed(**kwargs)
    484 

/home/harish/anaconda3/envs/facial_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/widget.py in _send(self, msg, buffers)
    485     def _send(self, msg, buffers=None):
    486         """Sends a message to the model in the front-end."""
--> 487         self.comm.send(data=msg, buffers=buffers)
    488 
    489 

/home/harish/anaconda3/envs/facial_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/comm.py in send(self, data, metadata, buffers)
    119         """Send a message to the frontend-side version of this comm"""
    120         self._publish_msg('comm_msg',
--> 121             data=data, metadata=metadata, buffers=buffers,
    122         )
    123 

/home/harish/anaconda3/envs/facial_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/comm.py in _publish_msg(self, msg_type, data, metadata, buffers, **keys)
     64         metadata = {} if metadata is None else metadata
     65         content = json_clean(dict(data=data, comm_id=self.comm_id, **keys))
---> 66         self.kernel.session.send(self.kernel.iopub_socket, msg_type,
     67             content,
     68             metadata=json_clean(metadata),

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'session'
<ipywidgets.widgets.widget_button.Button at 0x7f0ddadc2cc0>
```

Comment: Ubuntu terminal cannot support interactive widgets. You need to run it in a "browser"-like or GUI enabled environment that can run Javascript.

Comment: @AmitSingh so is there any other option apart from jupyter notebook

Comment: Jupyter notebook is not the problem, Ubuntu terminal is the problem. It does not support displaying images or widgets. If you are only trying to avoid using a browser, you can look at [Jupyter Qt console](http://qtconsole.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/).

Answer (score 0):

From user6764549 comments:

Ubuntu terminal cannot support interactive widgets. You need to run it in a "browser"-like or GUI enabled environment that can run Javascript.

Jupyter notebook is not the problem, Ubuntu terminal is the problem. It does not support displaying images or widgets. If you are only trying to avoid using a browser, you can look at [Jupyter Qt console](http://qtconsole.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/).